# Is it possible to embed YAML into a JSON payload?

Tags: json, yaml

Is it possible to embed YAML into a JSON payload? And if so, How?

I'm trying to come up with a JSON request which has a embedded YAML embedded, a very large YAML file at that:

```
    {
      "deployment":{
           "family":"mui",
           "assemblyfile": "large YAML file here"
       }
    }
```

Comment: I'm just curious why you'd do that?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question. You include that like any other text content. You would just replace newlines with `\n` and also escape other characters, where necessary.

Comment: I think that's the answer, the YAML file had lots of lines, specific indentations and linux commands in quotes..just have to go through and escape them patiently..

Answer (score 6):

So, apperently the question is about how to quote/escape the embedded text (YAML).

Try out [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), it offers a lot of sophisticated operations. This should do the trick:

```
# return your text properly escaped in "" quotes
jq --raw-input --slurp < file.yaml
```